# CV2 starts taking emty images after some time

Tags: python, opencv

i am new to python and i have a small problem. I am supposed to take images every 10 seconds with a webcam over a long period of time. My code works for about 5 hours or 1800 pictures, then all of a sudden the pictures i am saving are emty. I don't know whats causing the error and i don't get an error message, the skript keeps running.

I am using spyder with python 2.7. When i restart the kernel, my skript works again for a few hours. Here is my code:

```
import cv2
import time
import datetime
import os
data_path = 'V:\\Database\\Pictures'
try:
  while True:

       cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
       cam.set(3,1280) #set height
       cam.set(4,720) #set width
       s, im = cam.read() # captures image
    # Write date and time to image

       date_string = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
       font                   = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
       bottomLeftCornerOfText = (10,710)
       fontScale              = 1
       fontColor              = (255,255,255)
       lineType               = 2

       cv2.putText(im,date_string, 
           bottomLeftCornerOfText, 
           font, 
           fontScale,
           fontColor,
           lineType)


       temp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time())
       year = temp.year           
       month = temp.month
       day = temp.day
       hour = temp.hour
       minute = temp.minute
       second = temp.second

       imagename = year+'-'+month+'-'+day+'_'+hour+'-'+minute+'-   '+second+'.jpg'

         # writes image  to disk    
       cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(data_path,imagename),im)    
       cam.release()
       time.sleep(10)

finally:
  cam.release()
```

Is this a problem with my memory? Size of one picture is 261KB.

Answer (score 0):

Hard disk full? Not sure if this solves the problem but you should re-arrange your code. No need to re-initialize the camera every time:

```
import cv2
import time
import datetime
import os
data_path = 'V:\\Database\\Pictures'

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cam.set(3,1280) #set height
cam.set(4,720) #set width

font                   = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
bottomLeftCornerOfText = (10,710)
fontScale              = 1
fontColor              = (255,255,255)
lineType               = 2

while True:

    try:
        s, im = cam.read() # captures image
    except:
        # something here
        pass

    now = datetime.datetime.now()

    date_string = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

    cv2.putText(im,date_string, 
        bottomLeftCornerOfText, 
        font, 
        fontScale,
        fontColor,
        lineType)

    imagename = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S") + '.jpg'

    # writes image  to disk    
    cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(data_path,imagename),im)    
    time.sleep(10)

cam.release()
```

Comment: Thanks! The hard disk was not full but re-arranging the code helped!